# Set textbox so that is not tabable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using c# Validation Attributes on a `Textboxfor` field.  The textbox has been set to `readonly` because it gets its value from the sum of two other fields via Javascript. . Is it possible to also set the text box so that it is not able to be tabbed to or clicked on? I tried using a Displayfor, but validation was not working.

Here is the textboxfor that I'm using

```
<td>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NewLine.Total)
</td>
```

Comment: could you provide the markup?

Comment: why are you making it required/validated when the client shouldn't change it? you might reconsider your post back model.

Comment: If it's not a user-input value it probably shouldn't be in an input field to begin with.  (Nor should it need validation logic... If it's not valid what is the user supposed to do about that?)  In any event, you might try settings its `disabled` attribute.  It won't get posted that way, but if it's a calculated value then does it really need to be posted?  Can't it be, well, calculated?

Comment: try to set `TabIndex = -1`From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.tabindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) notes: `Only controls with a nonzero tab index will render the tabindex attribute.`

Comment: It's the sum of two other fields. The other two fields are validated to be greater than or equal to zero, but the sum must be greater that zero. In other words, at least one of the fields has to have some positive value that is greater than zero.

Comment: why don't you show it client side, but calculate it serverside?

Comment: you can write  custom validation logic for that.

Comment: @jbutler483 I have to show the sum client side so it must also be calculated server side

Comment: yea so don't have a field in your model that is required. use js and just have a dummy span that it updates.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NewLine.Total, new { @readonly="readonly" })
```

Which should make it readonly. there is also an attribute:

```
@enabled="false"
```

if i'm not mistaken

---

However, I know it may sound 'silly', but what don't you calculate it **server-side**, and then send it to your view? That way, since you have both of the values on both the server and client, you wouldn't need to:

1. Post it back, nor
2. Calculate it client side (which would probably be against MVC design
   pattern anyway)?

Comment: its disabled. and when its disabled, it doesn't get posted

Comment: unless you'd include a hiddenFor attribute?

Comment: If it's calculated from two input fields that do get posted, there's no need to post it anyway.

Comment: @jbutler483 I can still tab to the field after adding the the code in your post. Also the calcualtion is performed on two other texboxes that are editable by the user. So it needs to be done with javascript dynamically for the user to see the changes. That is,unless I do a postback everytime the value has changed.